# How to Add Post Build Handlers to AutoFixture

Tags: c#, autofixture

I have a use case where I want AutoFixture to build my object using the default method, but then I want to add some post handling to it because there are certain properties I then need to set dynamically after the object has been built.  However I want the posthandling to occur on all objects that derive from a specific type.  Is there any way to do this using AutoFixture?

Comment: You can do that [using a Postprocessor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21569388).

Answer (score 1):

AutoFixture automatically populates writable properties so you don't have to do anything in order to enable that. If you want some of the properties to be treated in a special way, you can define an `ISpecimenBuilder` for such properties, e.g.

```
public class StreetNameBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var pi = request as PropertyInfo;
        if (pi == null || pi.Name != "StreetName" || pi.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            return new NoSpecimen();

        return "Baker Street"; // Your custom value goes here.
    }
}
```

Such a builder, when registered, handles all `StreetName` properties of the type `string`, regardless of on which class that property is defined. If you want to target properties that are defined on a class that derives from a particular base class, then you can inspect `pi` for that information as well.

You need to register the builder with a `Fixture` instance, for example like this:

```
fixture.Customizations.Add(new StreetNameBuilder());
```